# CSS keyframe animation is not running when element's class is applied by javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a page involving multiple css animations. My objective: as the page scrolls thru a series of sections, a function applies a series of classes to an absolutely positioned element (the 'thing', which comes and goes throughout), which runs a keyframe animation according to the css class.

Classes are set on load to the first section and the abs pos element, and the first css animation of the thing is running fine. The problem is that, even though I can see the thing is getting the correct classes as the page scrolls, the corresponding animations are not running.

html:

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="thing-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="enable-background:new 0 0 60 60;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="thing-path-group">
            <path id="thing-path" d="M25.313,0.103c-1.789,1.724-2.727,4.989-3.638,7.156c-3.326,7.915-6.434,15.931-9.448,23.964 c-1.847,4.923-3.105,9.807-4.238,14.902c-0.181,0.82-0.404,1.511-0.752,2.264c-1.012,2.188-2.523,4.126-3.851,6.137 c-1.192,1.803-2.034,3.912-3.414,5.571c4.71-0.283,9.534-2.292,14.253-2.933c10.085-1.371,20.049-0.629,30.118,0.077 c5.03,0.35,10.369,0.483,15.201-0.976c-2.641-4.111-5.831-7.679-8.15-12.042c-2.742-5.157-5.317-10.727-8.843-15.439 c-1.816-2.43-3.04-5.247-5.1-7.486c-1.252-1.36-2.596-2.599-3.517-4.211c-0.51-0.896-0.559-1.765-0.904-2.656 c-0.339-0.874-0.646-1.31-1.25-2.176c-1.419-2.038-2.822-4.347-3.851-6.602c-0.776-1.701-1.001-4.141-2.758-5.142" />
        </g>
    </svg>

    <div class="sections">
        <div class="section" id="section-1"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section-2"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section-3"></div>
    </div> <!-- .sections -->
```

css:

```
#thing-svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
    top: -60px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999;
}

#thing-svg.section-1 { animation: section-1 1.8s ease-in-out forwards .3s; }
@keyframes section-1 {
    0% {
        top: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    3% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        top: 66%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#thing-svg.section-2 { animation: section-2 .9s ease-in-out forwards .3s; }
@keyframes section-2 {
    0% {
        top: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    3% {
        opacity: 1;
        border: 9px solid red;
    }
    100% {
        top: 36%;
        opacity: 1;
        border: 9px solid red;
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
function debounce(func, wait = 33, immediate = true) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}

const viewportHeight = function() {
    return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
}
const sectionsWrapper = document.querySelector('.sections');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const thing = document.querySelector('#thing-svg');
var prevPos = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var scrollingDown = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(updateSection));
thing.addEventListener('animationend', findthing);

function findthing(e) {
    return thingPosition = thing.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}


function updateSection(e) {

    const vpHeight = viewportHeight();

    var currPos = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (prevPos > currPos) {
        scrollingDown = false;
    } else {
        scrollingDown = true;
    }

    if (scrollingDown) {


        const thingPosition = findthing();

        sections.forEach((section, ix) => {

            var sectionId = section.getAttribute("id");
            var distanceFromTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (distanceFromTop < (vpHeight / 3) && distanceFromTop > -(2 * vpHeight / 3)) {
                section.classList.add('animate');
            }
            else {
                section.classList.remove('animate');
            }

        }); // forEach

        var activeSection = document.querySelector('.animate');
        var activeSectionId = activeSection.getAttribute("id");
        console.log("activeSectionId", activeSectionId);

        thing.classList = activeSectionId;

    } // if scrollingDown
    prevPos = currPos;

} // updateSection


window.onload = function() {
    var newScrollPos;
    var scrollPos = 0;

    window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
    });
    setTimeout(initFirstSection, 1500);
    function initFirstSection() {
        sections[0].classList.add("animate");
    }
    thing.classList.add("animation-1");

    sections.forEach(section => {
        section.style.height = viewportHeight();
    })

} // onload
```

```js
function debounce(func, wait = 33, immediate = true) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

const viewportHeight = function() {
  return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
}
const sectionsWrapper = document.querySelector('.sections');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const thing = document.querySelector('#thing-svg');
var prevPos = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var scrollingDown = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(updateSection));
thing.addEventListener('animationend', findthing);

function findthing(e) {
  return thingPosition = thing.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}


function updateSection(e) {

  const vpHeight = viewportHeight();

  var currPos = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (prevPos > currPos) {
    scrollingDown = false;
  } else {
    scrollingDown = true;
  }

  if (scrollingDown) {


    const thingPosition = findthing();

    sections.forEach((section, ix) => {

      var sectionId = section.getAttribute("id");
      var distanceFromTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      if (distanceFromTop < (vpHeight / 3) && distanceFromTop > -(2 * vpHeight / 3)) {
        section.classList.add('animate');
      } else {
        section.classList.remove('animate');
      }

    }); // forEach

    var activeSection = document.querySelector('.animate');
    var activeSectionId = activeSection.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("activeSectionId", activeSectionId);

    thing.classList = activeSectionId;

  } // if scrollingDown
  prevPos = currPos;

} // updateSection


window.onload = function() {
  var newScrollPos;
  var scrollPos = 0;

  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
  setTimeout(initFirstSection, 1500);

  function initFirstSection() {
    sections[0].classList.add("animate");
  }
  thing.classList.add("animation-1");

  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.style.height = viewportHeight();
  })

} // onload
```

```css
section { height: 100vh; }

.section#section-1 { background: red; }
.section#section-2 { background: lime; }
.section#section-3 { background: blue; }

#thing-svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  top: -60px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}

#thing-svg.section-1 {
  animation: section-1 1.8s ease-in-out forwards .3s;
}

@keyframes section-1 {
  0% {
    top: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 66%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#thing-svg.section-2 {
  animation: section-2 .9s ease-in-out forwards .3s;
}

@keyframes section-2 {
  0% {
    top: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  3% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 9px solid red;
  }
  100% {
    top: 36%;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 9px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="thing-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="enable-background:new 0 0 60 60;" xml:space="preserve">
   <g id="thing-path-group">
    <path id="thing-path" d="M25.313,0.103c-1.789,1.724-2.727,4.989-3.638,7.156c-3.326,7.915-6.434,15.931-9.448,23.964 c-1.847,4.923-3.105,9.807-4.238,14.902c-0.181,0.82-0.404,1.511-0.752,2.264c-1.012,2.188-2.523,4.126-3.851,6.137 c-1.192,1.803-2.034,3.912-3.414,5.571c4.71-0.283,9.534-2.292,14.253-2.933c10.085-1.371,20.049-0.629,30.118,0.077 c5.03,0.35,10.369,0.483,15.201-0.976c-2.641-4.111-5.831-7.679-8.15-12.042c-2.742-5.157-5.317-10.727-8.843-15.439 c-1.816-2.43-3.04-5.247-5.1-7.486c-1.252-1.36-2.596-2.599-3.517-4.211c-0.51-0.896-0.559-1.765-0.904-2.656 c-0.339-0.874-0.646-1.31-1.25-2.176c-1.419-2.038-2.822-4.347-3.851-6.602c-0.776-1.701-1.001-4.141-2.758-5.142" />
   </g>
  </svg>

<div class="sections">
  <div class="section" id="section-1"></div>
  <div class="section" id="section-2"></div>
  <div class="section" id="section-3"></div>
</div>
<!-- .sections -->
```

Comment: You are adding the class `section-` to 'thing', while your CSS is using `animation-`.

Comment: As @sol suggested you are adding the `section-1` `section-2` `section-3` class but your CSS animation is using the `animation-` class. Simply change the CSS class or the JS and you'll see the animation.

Comment: Thank you both, but this was an oversight in sanitizing my code for the post, which I've corrected (also updated the fiddle). As I said I *am* getting the correct classes applied to the thing but they're not animating when the classes are applied.

Comment: I put your code into a snippet. It's lacking the `debounce()` code though, and I can't just copy it over from your fiddle because of licensing. Could you please modify the snippet to be a fully workable example that illustrates your issue? It makes it easier for people to modify your code to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Tschallacka. I've updated the fiddle which is now here: https://jsfiddle.net/4fhLozn9/25/ ... and if you inspect the svg el you can see it's getting the classes

Comment: @WhiskeyT.Foxtrot I didn't mean the fiddle, but the snippet in your question. Offsite resources are subject to link rot(it vanishes) and won't help future answer seekers to evaluate if your question matches their scenario. If you click the edit link under your answer and then scroll down and click `edit the above snippet` to make the snippet match the fiddle example, you make it easier for people to help you. What also plays is that the code in the fiddle can't legally be used by others because it's all rights reserved. The license you share it on SO allows us to use it and modify to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Tschallacka, OP edited with the full js and hopefully I've un-botched the snippet